# Using variables in one class in another class NullpointerException - RunTimeException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I tried to do something extremely simple or I thought it was.

In my BluetoothChat, I set

```
public static boolean potato = false;
```

In the onCreateBundle of my MainActivity,
I have

```
if(BluetoothChat.potato == false)
{
  tv.setText("it did not crash");
}
```

My application crashes immediately upon me switching windows from bluetoothchat to mainactivity. I receive java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.NullPointerException. However, the application does not crash and switches perfectly if I have the if statement commented out.

Comment: The reason for this is that while the program control enters into onCreate() method, still your BluetoothChat class is Null. Hence it gives NPE.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: May be by calling a public constructor before your if condition.

Comment: give us complete stacktrace....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is coming from tv, not BlueToothChat.potato. Have you initialized the "tv" variable at that point in the code?

Comment: I feel really stupid right now. That worked. Thank you.

Comment: We all make this mistake once in a while! Whenever you get a NullPointerException, check for uninitialized variables; that's more often than not the problem.